# File(media) share across servers in IIS

Tags: wordpress, iis, media, image-uploading, windows-server-2012-r2

I have hosted my 2 WordPress websites in IIS (Windows 2012 R2) servers with a load balancer, where I use to upload images, Whenever I upload images or file from media manager via media it creates a file on individual servers I’m stuck with mounting upload folder in windows.

I have changed upload folder with virtual directory as shared folder to upload images this didn’t work.

Any help may greatly appreciated.